# Tool used to make Salesforce DataModel image

Tags: salesforce, entity-relationship, database-schema, datamodel

I was looking at the SalesForce data model. The image can be seen here below:

[image]

Does anyone know what tool that was used to make this?

This image was copied from http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm

More images can be found here:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm

Comment: You might also want to checkout the built in Schema Builder for creating diagrams directly in Salesforce.

Comment: That is a very nice utility... thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/er-diagram-tool

I think it might be this one?

Comment: Ahh, Thank you. That does look almost exactly the same. I need to look more into this. I was kind of hoping that they used an automatic tool, rather than one that was hand drawn. Give me a few minutes, once I can replicate an image I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Schema Builder is good for getting a data model of a few entities.  However, if you want to get something like the model shown in this thread, then you need more capability.    For example, you won't find 'AccountContactRole' in the Schema Builder.   That's an intersect between Account and Contact.

Take a look at Safyr from Silwood Technology - this pulls all the Objects (or tables) from your own SFDC instance and lets you choose which to include in a model.